# HTML executes different php function onclick

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following problem. No matter which image I click, function 2 gets executed. Thanks a lot for your help.

```
<l href='<?php echo function1(); ?>' onclick='alert("ON!")'> <IMG STYLE="position:relative; margin-top: 40px" SRC="/img/on.png" page="control.php"></l>   

<l href='<?php echo function2(); ?>' onclick='alert("OFF!")'> <IMG STYLE="position:relative; margin-top: 40px; margin-left: 80px" SRC="/img/off.png" page="control.php"></l>
```

The purpose of it is to execute different sql queries but they both execute the same query. The functions are included in a separate php. My only guess at the moment is that it is related to the styling.

The l> tag:

```
$( document ).on(
   "click",
   "l",
   function( event ){

    // Stop the default behavior of the browser, which
    // is to change the URL of the page.
         event.preventDefault();

        // Manually change the location of the page to stay in
        // "Standalone" mode and change the URL at the same time.
        location.href = $( event.target ).attr( "page" );

    }
);
```

Comment: What's up with the `<l>` tags? Shouldn't they be `<a>` instead?

Comment: Can you provide all related php code?

Comment: It is a web app for iPhone. The l tag just prevents it from opening in Safari.
 Added code in question.

Comment: @RomeoPopentiu You need to show code of `function1` and `function2` or at least explain what exactly are they doing and what is the returned value you're echoing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you haven't provided your php code yet here are my assumptions about your case:

`function1()` does some mysql query like that: `UPDATE t SET state='on'...`

`function2()` does almost the same: `UPDATE t SET state='off'...`

By using this code:

```
<?php echo function1(); ?> 
<?php echo function2(); ?>'
```

You are basically calling **both** functions. First one switches something on then second one turns it off again and makes you think that only second query was executed. There is a problem with the logic of your code.

You can achieve your goal by using `GET` variables and running first or second function depending on its value. Here's example script

PHP:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
    if ($_GET['action'] == "on") {
        function1();
    elseif ($_GET['action'] == "off") {
        function2();
    }
}

?>
```

HTML:

```
<span onclick="alert('ON!')"> <IMG STYLE="position:relative; margin-top: 40px" SRC="/img/on.png" page="control.php?action=on"></span>   

<span onclick="alert('OFF!')"> <IMG STYLE="position:relative; margin-top: 40px; margin-left: 80px" SRC="/img/off.png" page="control.php?action=off"></span>
```

Comment: I did not intend to alter the address because of the back button but I guess I do not have another choice. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @RomeoPopentiu You are welcome, just please be more specific next time. Also you can use POST instead of GET if you don't want to alter the address.

Comment: I definitely will! Thank you!